# CodeIgniter - Shared template variables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm repeatedly having to include one variable when I display my views:

```
$this->load->view('login', array('logged_in' => $this->auth->is_logged_in()));
$this->load->view('somepage', array('logged_in' => $this->auth->is_logged_in()));
$this->load->view('anotherpage', array('logged_in' => $this->auth->is_logged_in()));
```

How can I include this one variable across all of my view outputs? Is there a simpler method than extending the templating class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simpler way would be to make the array into a variable, so you dont have to type it out all the time, e.g.

```
$params = array('logged_in' => $this->auth->is_logged_in());
$this->load->view('login', $params);
$this->load->view('somepage', $params);
$this->load->view('anotherpage', $params);
```

An alternative would be to create a Helper that returns whether a user is logged in. Helpers are globally available in your controllers and views. See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html and also

- [CodeIgniter: Create new helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper)

Comment: I went with the helper option. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

how about using sessions?

```
$this->session->userdata($var);
```

or cookies

```
$this->input->cookie($var, TRUE);
```

thanks.

Comment: Note that current Codeigniter sessions are Cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Great solution, **Gordon**! But, depending on the case, it's also possible to use the [Most Simple Template Library](http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_template).

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can also access the class directly from within your view:

```
<?php if( $this->auth->is_logged_in() ): ?>
  Hello!
<?php endif; ?>
```

It's not the greatest solution but I find it works well with user conditionals.