# CodeIgniter - Globally load all tables for each controller

Tags: codeigniter

I have about 10 tables I need to load for each controller. Right now I am loading each one in every controller. What is the best way to just load them once and have access to them in each controller. I tried putting them in system/core/Controller.php `class CI_Controller` and it works. But I am sure this is not the best way to go about it. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "Load tables"?

Comment: Like when you store the table from a database into a variable. ex. `$all_users`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to load everything all at once, you can create a helper method that you will call in the constructor of each of your controllers.

Link to creating helper method - [CodeIgniter: Create new helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps MVC might be key?

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/models.html

One does not typically load an entire database table...I mean... would you load it into a global constant or something?

The old school way of doing things is to load what you need when you need it. When you need it, you load it. If you don't need it, why load it?

Maybe I don't understand.

Comment: I guess it is more of a proof of concept. I am just trying to learn code igniter by building a small application. I am trying different things to see what works best.

Comment: Ok cool. Yeah, definitely check out the link I posted. Models are an integral (though not required) part of CodeIgniter. Have fun!