# To insert current date into mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter

In this below code i have used codeigniter code i can insert username,password,first name,lastname and email address but i cant insert current date pls help to rectify this issue.

Controller:login

```
function create_member()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');


        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('signup_form');
        }

        else
        {           
            $this->load->model('membership_model');

            if($query = $this->membership_model->create_member())
            {
                $data['main_content'] = 'signup_successful';
                $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->load->view('signup_form');           
            }
        }

    }
```

model membership_model

*

```
function create_member()
    {

        $new_member_insert_data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email_address' => $this->input->post('email_address'),         
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'date' => $this->input->post('date','curdate()'),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))                       
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_insert_data);
        if ($this->db->_error_number() == 1062)
                {
                echo"<script>alert('This value already exists');</script>";
                }
                if ($this->db->_error_number() == "")
                {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('create', 'create');
                }

        return $insert;
    }
```

Comment: what is your curdate()? is that a php function or pertaining to CURDATE() sql function?

Comment: i refer to a site and add curdate()

Comment: Also, for password storage don't use `MD5`. Use `SHA1` or higher.

Comment: @Chris because of the password hack issue?

Comment: It is said that using md5 produces hash collisions.

Comment: MD5 is no longer considered secure. And yes, it produces a `128` bit output, which is less than `SHA1` at `192 bits` and `SHA2` which ranges from `256-512` bits.

Answer (score 1):

You may put this to one of your helpers:

```
function curdate() {
    // gets current timestamp
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila'); // What timezone you want to be the default value for your current date.
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

And use it like this:

```
'date' => $this->input->post('date',curdate()), // curdate() as a function
```

If you want to use this kind of thing globally, you may put this on a custom helper and autoload it. Refer to his link [CodeIgniter: Create new helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper)

**NOTE :** In my case here I was tasked to define the default timezone for the website. You may use UTC if you want

Comment: Better still bung in dates/times as UTC. Convert for the location of the user. People do change time zones. Especially pilots!

Comment: It's up to him.hehehe.thanks :) just giving insights

Comment: hey,how are you? sorry for late response. Have you made it work already? I updated my answer.