# CodeIgniter: where should I put custom utils?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and I have a few utils that I want each controller (that is, each controller file) to have access to.

The question is: **where to put these?**

I thought of helpers, but the CI documentation [talks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html) only about extending existing helpers, not making your own. I'm sure that doesn't mean I can't make my own helpers, but it does mean I don't know how they should be built (procedural? Methods of the global CI instance? etc)

I also considered hooks, but this is a poor fit I think as I'm not extending core functionality.

Or is there some other way I'm missing?

Comment: CodeIgniter 2.1.4? Helpers are generally just files with stand-alone functions which can be called upon for very distinct tasks. If you want your entire application to have access to it then add it to the `/application/helpers/specific_tasks_helper.php` folder and then autoload it in `/application/config/autoload.php` by adding `specific_tasks` to the `$autoload['helper']` array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done this but I believe I used two approaches.

- Creating a new, custom helper that goes into `/application/helpers`, following steps noted from this answer: [CodeIgniter: Create new helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper)
- Creating a new library class into `/application/libraries` which I also activate in the autoload configuration found in `/applications/config/autoload.php`.  This way it's always available to my controllers when I need it.  CI has good documentation on this one (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

Answer (score 1):

I did it simply by adding a file to the `application/helpers` folder (maybe I created that folder - I can't remember) and then loading them in the usual way.

Comment: The thing is, though, helpers seem to be for procedural, static functions, whereas I'm looking to use common methods, i.e. methods all of my controllers have access to.

Comment: You mentioned helpers in your question - in CI, helpers are functions. If you want class methods that all controllers have access to, then you're talking about something different. I think what you're probably looking for is a common base class for all your controllers to inherit from - if that's the case, then you can put your base class in the controllers directory.

Comment: Yeah this is the point another commenter was making. I was unaware of the existence of these before today :) Thanks.