# how to save helper in particular folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a helper in codeigniter and i did it . But my helper have some other files too. I want to create a folder  . But do not know how to call it in my controller.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper

Comment: @Mr.M imho, not really, close enough but the OP is not asking for a looping structure

Comment: Add your current code so we can get idea, What you mean by have other file ? is that mean file located in different folder ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is directory_map 
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/directory_helper.html

but i would add the folder to the existing helper folder
sub directories are automaticly mapped, you can then add all files in your autoloader

```
$autoload['helper'] = [
    'form', 'html', 'url', 'array',
    'function_helper', 'subdir/file1' , 'subdir/file2' , 'subdir/file3' 
];
```

something like this should do, ofcourse, you can also create a loop to do this