# where to place global function in codeigniter for SMS?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I want to create the global function in codeigniter for sending the SMS.
Whenever I want to send SMS simply I just call these global function i.e. SMS then where to write these function.

Comment: You can check this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper , there is written how to create helper class and in which you can create your sendSms method

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter comes pre-packaged with a lot of [helper functions](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html). So you can make a call to, let's say, `site_url()` wherever you want across your application. You can write your own custom helpers as well.

Create a `sms_helper.php` in your `application/helpers` directory, add your functions, a `sms()` maybe. Then autoload it in `application/config/autoload.php`:

```php
$autoload['helper'] = ['sms', ...];
```

Now, you can call `sms()` wherever you want.

If you don't autoload it, you need to `$this->load->helper('sms');` before you call any helper functions provided by that helper.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this function in the custom helper file in folder **application\helpers**. In this folder create a file **common_functions_helper.php** and create a function directly like

```
function sendSMS($data = array()){
  // function body
}
```

and load this file in a function where you want to call this function 
Like

```
$this->load->helper('common_functions');
```

and call the sms function by function name

```
sendSMS();
```