# Unable to load the requested file: helpers/files_helper.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting error in my codeignitor application:

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/files_helper.php

Can you please elaborate where is the issue?

File: autoload.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Instructions
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| These are the things you can load automatically:
|
| 1. Packages
| 2. Libraries
| 3. Drivers
| 4. Helper files
| 5. Custom config files
| 6. Language files
| 7. Models
|
*/

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Packages
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|  $autoload['packages'] = array(APPPATH.'third_party', '/usr/local/shared');
|
*/
$autoload['packages'] = array();

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Libraries
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| These are the classes located in system/libraries/ or your
| application/libraries/ directory, with the addition of the
| 'database' library, which is somewhat of a special case.
|
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session');
|
| You can also supply an alternative library name to be assigned
| in the controller:
|
|   $autoload['libraries'] = array('user_agent' => 'ua');
*/
$autoload['libraries'] = array( 'database', 'user_agent', 'image_lib', 'encryption', 'object_cache', 'email', 'app', 'gateways/app_gateway', 'sms' );

$CI = &get_instance();

$CI->load->helper('files');
$gateways = list_files(APPPATH.'/libraries/gateways');

foreach ($gateways as $gateway) {
    $pathinfo =  pathinfo($gateway);
    // Check if file is .php and do not starts with .dot
    // Offen happens Mac os user to have underscore prefixed files while unzipping the zip file.
    if ($pathinfo['extension'] == 'php' && 0 !== strpos($gateway, '.') && $pathinfo['filename'] != 'App_gateway') {
        array_push($autoload['libraries'], 'gateways/'.strtolower($pathinfo['filename']));
    }
}
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Drivers
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| These classes are located in system/libraries/ or in your
| application/libraries/ directory, but are also placed inside their
| own subdirectory and they extend the CI_Driver_Library class. They
| offer multiple interchangeable driver options.
|
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['drivers'] = array('cache');
*/
$autoload['drivers'] = array('session');

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Helper Files
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
*/
$autoload['helper'] = array(
        'url',
        'file',
        'form',
        'action_hooks',
        'general',
        'misc',
        'func',
        'datatables',
        'custom_fields',
        'defaults',
        'merge_fields',
        'app_html',
        'email_templates',
        'invoices',
        'estimates',
        'credit_notes',
        'proposals',
        'projects',
        'tasks',
        'fields',
        'tickets',
        'relation',
        'tags',
        'pdf',
        'clients',
        'database',
        'upload',
        'sales',
        'themes',
        'theme_style',
        'pre_query_data_formatters',
        'widgets',
        'sms',
        'deprecated',
    );

if (file_exists(APPPATH.'helpers/system_messages_helper.php')) {
    array_push($autoload['helper'], 'system_messages');
}

if (file_exists(APPPATH.'helpers/my_functions_helper.php')) {
    array_push($autoload['helper'], 'my_functions');
}
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Config files
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['config'] = array('config1', 'config2');
|
| NOTE: This item is intended for use ONLY if you have created custom
| config files.  Otherwise, leave it blank.
|
*/
$autoload['config'] = array();

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Language files
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['language'] = array('lang1', 'lang2');
|
| NOTE: Do not include the "_lang" part of your file.  For example
| "codeigniter_lang.php" would be referenced as array('codeigniter');
|
*/
$autoload['language'] = array('english');

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Models
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['model'] = array('first_model', 'second_model');
|
| You can also supply an alternative model name to be assigned
| in the controller:
|
|   $autoload['model'] = array('first_model' => 'first');
*/
$autoload['model'] = array( 'misc_model' , 'roles_model' , 'clients_model' , 'tasks_model' );

if(file_exists(APPPATH.'config/my_autoload.php')){
    include_once(APPPATH.'config/my_autoload.php');
}
```

The path in my codeigitor application of this file is application/config/autoload.php
I'm just trying to login from the base URL: http://crm.thecoder.pw/
And I'm getting this error: Unable to load the requested file: helpers/files_helper.php

Comment: Maybe this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper

Comment: @axiac dude seriously ??  It was there in mine :P

Comment: Tried it, getting 500 error.

Comment: just out of curiosity - the amount of helper files you are autoloading seems a bit odd - what are you doing with them ? ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is no helper call `files_helper`. Use [**`file`**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/file_helper.html)

```
$this->load->helper('file');
```

or in [**`/config/autoload.php`**](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/autoload.php#L92)

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('file');
```

---

**EDIT 01**

If you're creating new helper check  **[this answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper)**

Comment: @downvoter any reason ?. Know you like to hide yourself from truth

Comment: **`One of the fixes you suggest is already in use in the OP's project`** how you know this there already?  Since OP didnt mention third part helper then its from default helper file. !!

Comment: remove these from autoload `$CI = &get_instance();

$CI->load->helper('files');`

Comment: Read **[CodeIgniter: Create new helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper)**

Comment: Tried removing them, getting 500 error on front-end.

Comment: check the above link how to create and use helper

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I misread the first sentence of your answer and downvoted it based on the incorrect assumption that you suggest to **add** one of those lines of code. I want to retract my downvote but SO doesn't allow me until you modify the answer. Please edit the answer.

Comment: I have tried it. Its not solving the problem either. You can check the code in the Autoload Helpers section, its already 'file'

Comment: @axiac Yes please, I've tried it, gives out 500 error.

Comment: @axiac its already loaded in Helper array. So removing it wont be any issue

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to move my `custom_helper.php` from `application/helpers/custom_helper.php`
to `system/helpers/custom_helper.php` and in `application/config/autoload.php $autoload['helper'] = array('custom');`

Reload page and it work fine

Answer (score 2):

I think you have created helper in application/helpers folder.
You have to create helper in **system/helpers** folder instead of **application/helpers**.
Then load `$this->load->helper('files');`

Answer (score 2):

There should not be an upper case latter in helpers name.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a simple mistake that you have made, Replace below line of your code

```
$CI->load->helper('files');
```

by

```
$CI->load->helper('file');
```