# Undefined function when calling extended helper function in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I create `MY_form_helper.php` in `application/helpers/`, extending `form_helper.php`. The function is like this:

```
function alert($message,$type = 'success'){
    $data = array(
        'type' => $type,
        'text' => $message
    );
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

In my controller I call the function like this:

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
echo alert('Wrong email or password');
```

but it gives me an error

```
Message: Call to undefined function alert()
```

so what am I missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be working just fine as it is IF you stored it in the right directory which is **`application/helpers`** with the name **`MY_form_helper.php`** now you it should add the extension to the core helper:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
var_dump(alert('Wrong email or password'));
```

**Tested**

Answer (score 0):

Place your `MY_form_helper.php` helper to **application/helper**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

   function alert($message,$type = 'success'){
      $data = array(
        'type' => $type,
        'text' => $message
   );
   return json_encode($data);
}
```

and in your Controller place this code.

```
public function sample()
{
    $this->load->helper('MY_form_helper'); //load your helper

    echo alert('Wrong email or password'); //call your function
}
```

Let me know the result.

Comment: i did but still error. now it said Unable to load the requested file: helpers/my_form_helper.php

Comment: did you save your MY_form_helper.php helper to application/helper ?

Comment: it suppose to be application/helpers right? yes, i put in that folder already.

Comment: that's right then did you load this? $this->load->helper('MY_form_helper'); to your controller?

Comment: yes i try that already, but it give me others error said it's not found. since if i do that it will looking my file at system/helpers/ right? at least that what error said.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper click that link maybe it has a better explanation how to solve your problem.