# How to get nearest lat long in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have following array and according to my "Lat,Long" (dynamic) i want to get nearby locations from array,how can i do this ?
Here is my lat long

```
$lat="30.741190";
$lng="76.806343";
```

Here is my array

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CityName] => Jaunpur
            [distance] => 1.2316498252150263
            [latitude] => 30.741190
            [longitude] => 76.764381
            )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CityName] => Def
            [distance] => 3.710097860029201
            [latitude] => 30.740700
            [longitude] => 76.806343
             )
)
```

Comment: If your array already contains the distance, what problem do you have in getting the details you want?

Answer (score 1):

I use a function :

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
      return ($miles * 1.609344 );
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
  } else {
      return $miles;
  }
}
```

Now loop over array

```
$distances = array();
    foreach($arrayname as $ind => $entry){
    $dist=distance($entry["latitude"],$entry["longitude"],$lat,$lng,"K");
    echo $dist;
$distances[$entry["cityname"]]=round($dist);
    }
```

//now sort distances array in ascending:

```
$distances = sort($distances);
```

Comment: i am getting error "Call to undefined function distance()"

Comment: @user15018150 , add the function , i ve already provided it in the answer

Comment: i am working on codeigniter, So how can I use this function kindly explain

Comment: @user15018150 maybe try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper

Comment: you mean to say i have to create new helper and put your code in that helper, right ? will this work ?

Comment: @user15018150 if you don't want to these things , add the code of function directly in your loop and change variable name accordingly