# how to use another controller function without extends in our controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to  use another controller function without extends in our controller

> $this->load->library('../controllers/controllername');

already used
it is giving error =

> Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately your question is unclear - both in terms of what you want to achieve (and why), and the context of what might be causing it. You need to provide a clearer description of your goal and also a [mre] of the issue, not just an isolated line of code and an incomplete error message. Remember we cannot read your screen or your mind :-). See also the [tour] and [ask] to improve your experience on Stackoverflow. Then please edit your question so we could help you.

Answer (score 2):

Well you are not supposed to do that. If your controller uses repeatable logic, you should make class (Service for example), put the re-usable logic into it and call it in your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use another controller function inside the controller. You can archive this in these two ways.

1. [Create a Helper class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper)
2. [Create a generic model.](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/model.html)