# How to call controller function in another controller function in Codeigniter PHP without extends

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My first controller is "zoom" and the second controller is "user". How can I call the zoom controller function into the User controller without class extends?

Comment: But why ??? Controller to Controller  ?? If you have a common method, use a Model instead.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam , because I want to create a separate zoom controller, and When I need I have only called this, the reason for the speed issue. like library, but if I create library, in this file I don't use default $this->db function for get data into DB/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use another controller function inside the controller without extend. You can archive this in these two ways.

1. [Create a Helper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804399/codeigniter-create-new-helper)
2. [Create a generic model.](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/model.html)